# if condition remains idle when debugging

Tags: vb.net

When debugging this part executes smoothly

```
 Private Sub copythat()
    '*************MOVING to hrb FROM OTK*******************

    If FORK.ComboBox1.Text = "OTK" And ListBox2.Text = "HRB" Then
        Try
            Dim strconnectionsrting = ClsFuncs.connstring("connectionstring1")
            Dim cmdin As New SqlCommand
            Dim cnnoledb As New SqlConnection
            cnnoledb.ConnectionString = strconnectionsrting
            cnnoledb.Open()
            If bsknum <> "" Then
                cmdin.CommandText = "insert into dbo.HRB_inlet([basket_id],[operator_name],[dte],[tme],[quantity],[resistance],[FLG])values('" & Label2.Text & "','" & Label3.Text & "','" & Label4.Text & "','" & Label5.Text & "','" & Label6.Text & "','" & Label7.Text & "','2')"
                'cmdin.CommandText = "insert into dbo.HRB_inlet select * from dbo.outlet where basket_id = '" & bsknum & "'"
                cmdin.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmdin.Connection = cnnoledb
                cmdin.ExecuteNonQuery()

                cnnoledb.Close()

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to MOVE PRODUCT", "ERROR")
            End If
            deletion()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

But when it reaches the following `ELSEIF` statement the program doesn't do anything.

```
  'FROM STR 31 TO TESTBAY
  ElseIf FORK.ComboBox1.Text = "31 STR" And ListBox2.Text = "TESTBAY" Then
            Try
                Dim strconnectionsrting = ClsFuncs.connstring("connectionstring1")
                Dim cmdrd As New SqlCommand
                Dim cnnoledb As New SqlConnection
                cnnoledb.ConnectionString = strconnectionsrting
                cnnoledb.Open()
                cmdrd.CommandText = "INSERT into testbay select *  from dbo.str31 where str31.outlet_packaging_id in (select outlet_packaging_id from str31 where outlet_packaging_id = '" & bsknum & "')"
                cmdrd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmdrd.Connection = cnnoledb
                cmdrd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cnnoledb.Close()
                deletion()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
endif
```

I'm quite new to VB so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the values of `FORK.ComboBox1.Text` and `ListBox2.Text` when you get to this? And what does `deletion()` do?

Comment: lol, I love the edit's. Maybe a little bit more information other than the program doesn't do anything would help. Also I'd like to point out you have the potential for SQL injection in you code. Lastly your variable / table / Sub Procedure names are pretty terrible think of the poor sod who has to pick this up after you.

Comment: `And` should be `AndAlso` (and `Or` is `OrElse`)! Unrelated, but should be fixed anyway.

Comment: heheh deletion() moves or rather copies a row in the slq database table to another table . Lemme try the andalso thanks everyone i'll be back with feedback asap

Comment: and how do you prevent sql injection? do yu have any links that might help?